# Loop a part of code for multiple variables

Tags: shell-script, for

I am looking for an approach to build a script.

I have 3 files with the below pattern:

```
DailyLoad_Cust.txt
DailyLoad_Credit.txt
DailyLoad_Account.txt
```

Each of these files has an associated `sub_system`.
e.g `cust` has `cus_edw`, `credit` has `cred_edw` and `account` has `acc_edw`.

There is a common load script `RunFeed.sh <<sub_system>>` which takes `sub_system`  (`cus_edw`,`cred_edw`, or `acc_edw`) and runs if the file is available at NAS location and has `count` > 0.

What's the best approach I can use for this?

```
$Var1="Cust"
$Var2="Credit"
$var3="Account"

SUB_SYSTEM="";
for i in $VAR1; do

NASFileCount=`find . -maxdepth l -type f -name "${var}*.txt" | wc -l
if [[ $NASFileCount -gt 0 ]] && $Var1=cust;then
 Sub_System=cust_edw
    sh RunFeed.sh $Var
```

In the above approach (which is raw and not run so far), how can I run the loop for all the variables above?

Can anyone please guide me, there is any better approach?
I am relatively new to Unix, still learning.

Comment: Set array of strings

Comment: What does "has count > 0" actually mean? Does it just mean "Run `sh RunFeed.sh account_edw` if the file `DailyLoad_Account.txt` is available in the current directory"?

Comment: @they Thanks for your response and guide. Each file is associated with a sub_system which tells from where the file comes like for cust it's cust_edw. My first task is to check the file count of each, if it's gt -0 or not. only if gt -0 then proceed to run the runfeed.sh which takes sub_system as a parameter. The sub_system also has to be set as per the mentioned example. like for file cust, set the sub_syetem to cust_edw and the pass it to runfeed.sh

Answer (score 2):

We're going to assume that you want to run `RunFeed.sh` with the `_edw` subsystem string corresponding to whatever `DailyLoad_*.txt` file exists in the current directory as an argument.

To test for the existence of a name, use an `-e` test.  To do this over a set of values, use a loop.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for string in account credit cust; do
        if [ -e "DailyLoad_${string^}.txt" ]; then
                sh RunFeed.sh "${string}_edw"
        fi
done
```

What's happening here is that we iterate over the three strings `account`, `credit`, and `cust`.  For each of these strings in `$string`, we test whether the name `DailyLoad_${string^}.txt` exists or not, where `${string^}` will up-case the first character of the string in `$string`.

If the name exists, we run the `RunFeed.sh` shell script with `${string}_edw` as the only argument.

If you want to test not only for existence but also for whether the file is non-empty, use `-s` in place of `-e` in the test above.  An `-s` test would fail for files of zero length.

---

There are several basic syntax errors in your code.

- Assigning to variables that are prefixed by `$`.  Doing this is syntactically valid shell-code under some obfuscated circumstances but does not do what you expect. In general, assignments should be done to variable names (`variable=value`), not to the expansion of variables (<s>`$variable=value`</s>).
- The command substitution around `find` and `wc` is missing a final backtick.
- You are using `l` (ell) rather than `1` (one) with the `-maxdepth` option of `find`.
- The `if` statement lacks `fi`, and the `for` loop is missing its `done` at the end.
- You have unused variables, and you use others that are never assigned values.
- You don't quote some expansions that need double-quoting.

You may find the https://www.shellcheck.net/ website handy for weeding out syntax errors in your shell-code.

Comment: Thanks @they  for sharing the site. I am completely new to unix. Still learning. Hope my response/requirement is clear now.

Comment: +1. It's hard to tell from the way that the OP wrote their question, but you might want to use `-s` ("True if file exists and is not empty.") for the test instead of `-e` ("True if file exists.").   Run `help test` in bash for details.

Comment: @cas Thank you. I added a short notice about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that was your meaning, please do comment if I misunderstand your meaning.

**First: you can use arrays and ittarate over them.**

As [Romeo Ninov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/101265/romeo-ninov) mentioned, you can utilize it with arrays.
Consider the following code:

```
ARRAY_VALS={"Cust" "Credit" "Account"}
for value in "${ARRAY_VALS[@]}"; do echo $value; done
```

**Second: subsystem suffix**

I'm assuming that you probably have multiple suffixes, but what is the sub-system file used for? You don't actually use it anywhere. Anyway, you can use something like the following code to create it:

```
SUB_SYSTEM=${value}"_edw"
```

Or if you need to find the full name:

```
SUB_SYSTEM=`find . -maxdepth l -type f -name "*${value}_edw.txt"`
```

**Third: file names**

By your example, your searching for files with "cust*" or "*cust"? Because you said your files are in the following format: "DailyLoad_Cust.txt", meaning: "*cust".
In that case, however - you should verify that you have only the required prefix (in this case: "DailyLoad". For example, if the amended code is:

```
NASFileCount=`find . -maxdepth l -type f -name "*${value}*.txt" | wc -l`
```

So you can filter it, if needed, with grep:

```
NASFileCount=`find . -maxdepth l -type f -name "*${value}*.txt"| grep "DailyLoad" | wc -l`
```

**The final code**

I changed your code a bit and added fi (to and the if condition) and done (for the for). Please comment if I misunderstand:

```
Var1="Cust"
Var2="Credit"
var3="Account"

ARRAY_VALS=($Var1 $Var2 $Var3) # Daclare an array
for value in "${ARRAY_VALS[@]}"; do # run the for loop
    NASFileCount=`find . -maxdepth l -type f -name "*${value}*.txt" | wc -l`
        if [[ $NASFileCount -gt 0 ]] && "$Var1"==cust;then
            SUB_SYSTEM=${value}"_edw" # not used
            sh RunFeed.sh "$SUB_SYSTEM" # Run subscript
    fi
done
```

Comment: You seem to carry over some obvious syntax errors from the user's code, like using `$` on variable names when assigning values to them.  You also lack quoting of some variable expansions. Furthermore, `var3` seems unused.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @david Thanks for your response and guide. Each file is associated with a sub_system which tells from where the file comes like for cust it's cust_edw. My first task is to check the file count of each, if it's gt -0 or not. only if gt -0 then proceed to run the runfeed.sh which takes sub_system as a parameter. The sub_system also has to be set as per the mentioned example. like for file cust, set the sub_syetem to cust_edw and the pass it to runfeed.sh

Comment: @they thank you kindly. I fixed most of the typos I think. For the code clearance and readability, I didn't quote some of the variables