# Add values to an array and loop based on that

Tags: shell-script, for

I have 3 files like below:

```
CV_REF_DATA_09012021.txt
DB_ONLINE_CL_09012021.txt
DFR_CL_INS_09012021.txt
```

I want to check if the files are present in /NAS/CFG/ and then add it to an array.
It's not required that all the 3 files are present at all times. So, it can either be 1, 2 or all the 3 files. If there are no files the script should exit saying the same.
Next I want to loop based on the array and run a "call" script.

The call script uses the file pattern to check the file count as well.
Below code from call script.

```
NASFilecnt=`find . -type f -name "${CV_REF_DATA}*.txt" | wc -l`
```

So, how can run the loop based on the above. Please let me know if there are any queries.

Comment: Why not `for f in /NAS/CFG/*.txt; do whatever $f ; done`?

Comment: But I want to loop only for the 3 mentioned files( there can be many .txt files at the location)  and also those filenames i want to utilise in my call script inside loop.

Comment: Have you tried enabling bash nullglob? `shopt -s nullglob; for f in /NAS/CFG/{CV_REF_DATA_09012021.txt,DB_ONLINE_CL_09012021.txt,DFR_CL_INS_09012021.txt}*; do whatever $f ; done`. The file name is used as an argument in whatever script you call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of what you want to happen, depending on the existence of the files, is a bit vague. It's also unclear if you wish to collect the names separately for each filename prefix or together.  It may also be better to pick a particular date, for example, and try to find the set of files from that.  The code below should provide a bit of support for your programming effort.

This answer will be similar to my response to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/670723/493832) in that we will loop over a set of static strings to test whether filenames containing those strings exists or not.

You may loop over the filename prefixes, and in each iteration, check whether any file with that prefix (and with the `.txt` filename suffix) exists.

```bsh
for prefix in CV_REF_DATA_ DB_ONLINE_CL_ DFR_CL_INS_; do
        set -- /NAS/CFG/"$prefix"*.txt
        if [ -e "$1" ]; then
                printf 'There exists names matching "%s"*.txt:\n' "$prefix"
                printf '\t%s\n' "$@"
        else
                printf 'No names matches "%s"*.txt\n' "$prefix"
        fi
done
```

The loop iterates over the filename prefixes, and in each iteration, we try to expand the pattern that should match the files we are interested in for that prefix.  The `set` command will store the matching filenames in the list of positional parameters (`"$@"`; `"$1"` is the first element of that list).

In the `bash` shell, we may write the above block of code as follows.

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

for prefix in CV_REF_DATA_ DB_ONLINE_CL_ DFR_CL_INS_; do
        names=( /NAS/CFG/"$prefix"*.txt )
        if [ "${#names[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
                printf 'There exists names matching "%s"*.txt:\n' "$prefix"
                printf '\t%s\n' "${names[@]}"
        else
                printf 'No names matches "%s"*.txt\n' "$prefix"
        fi
done
```

The `nullglob` shell option makes non-matching globbing patterns disappear rather than remain unexpanded. We use a named array, `names`, to hold any matching filenames in each iteration.

---

For a literal interpretation of your issue: Call some other script if at least one of the tree filenames `CV_REF_DATA_09012021.txt`,
`DB_ONLINE_CL_09012021.txt`,
`DFR_CL_INS_09012021.txt` exists in the directory `/NAS/CFG`. Add the existing names to an array.

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
unset -v names

for name in CV_REF_DATA_09012021.txt DB_ONLINE_CL_09012021.txt DFR_CL_INS_09012021.txt
do
        [ -e /NAS/CFG/"$name" ] && names+=( "$name" )
done

if [ "${#names[@]}" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'no files could be found' >&2
        exit 1
fi

# At least one name is in the "names" array.
# Call your other script below here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @they. Ran the basic code and its coming as expected. Will update you once i run the entire part.